# Research plan vs proposed research for class project?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, coursework

A proposal format for that class project requires student to provide research plan as well as proposed approach. Can you please help me in understanding differences between the two?

Comment: From which standpoint are you asking? As a student, advisor, or instructor?

Answer (score 1):

In general a research plan will **include** within it a section that deals with the proposed approach. As [this University of Michigan page explains](http://orsp.umich.edu/research-proposals-plan-or-approach):

> Research Plan (Approach)
>
> This section includes a comprehensive explanation of the proposed
>   research, and is addressed to other specialists in your field (not to
>   laymen). The section is the heart of the proposal and is the primary
>   concern of the technical reviewers. To make it clear and easy to
>   follow, you may need several subsections tailored to your work.
>   Research design is a large subject and cannot be covered here, but a
>   few reminders concerning frequently mishandled aspects of proposals
>   may be helpful.

As always, you should talk with your advisor/professor to ensure if this is exactly what they have in mind, or if there is some specific template or example for your field/subject/use that you should follow.